# Tensorflow: how to train NeuralNet?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am inspired by the possibilities of TensorFlow and want to  write a AI with a Neural Net that is optimizing a strategy fpr a single player board game. I get the code running, but the strategies are not improving. My Game impelmentation seems to be working fine. (its simple right now: get a ressource A, or a ressource B, or exchange al ressource for victoryPoints, so the smart thing would be to accumalate some ressources that exchange them.)
I guess I am not training the model.

I tried understanding code examples, but it's just a bit much for a python starter. 
So what I know is I want to have a model which is evalutating a state, so it gets a state as an input, and the output is just one value: how good the state is, so how many vistory points are expected to be scored.
This I use to forecast the next ~3 rounds and then pick the action that leads to the best result in ~3 rounds accourding to the NeuralNetwork (and in the beginning a random selection is used instead, getting less); and start all over.
I am really unsure how this "predict" (I think thats an evaluation) and "update" (I hope thats a training) is supposed to work.

```
class NeuralNet():
def __init__(self):
     # Placeholders for inputs (x) and outputs(y)

    self.x_pl = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, game.getStateSize(game())], name='X')
    self.y_pl = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.float32, name="y")

    self.fc1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(self.x_pl, 64)
    self.fc2 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(self.fc1, 64)
    self.output = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(self.fc2, 1)
    self.value = self.output[0]

    self.loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(self.y_pl-self.output))

    self.train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1.0).minimize(self.loss)

def predict(self, sess, s):
    """
    Predicts value of state(?).
    Args:
      sess: Tensorflow session
      s: State input of shape [batch_size, 4, 160, 160, 3]
    Returns:
      Tensor containing the estimated
      state value.
    """
    s = np.expand_dims(s, 0)
    return sess.run(self.value, {self.x_pl: s})

def update(self, sess, s, y):
    """
    Updates the NeuralNet so its predicting better(?).
    Args:
      sess: Tensorflow session object
      s: State of game
      y: VictoryPoints Actualy Earned at the end
    Returns:
      nothing yet
    """
    s = np.expand_dims(s, 0)
    y = np.expand_dims(y, 0)
    feed_dict = {self.x_pl: s, self.y_pl: y}
    sess.run([WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE, tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step(), self.train, self.loss], feed_dict)
```

in the main class the following is called:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
deep_q_learning(sess)
```

and then i am basicly going through the many epochs/episodes and playing one game each epoch. for the predictions I need there I use

```
neurnet.predict(sess, g.getGameState())
```

and I am trying to use

```
nn.update(sess, state, game.points)
```

at the end of an epoch to update, but that doesn't work technicly right now (TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type ).
(

As without the update-line, the code runs through but the strategies are so bad it hardly scores any victory points (I guess random strategies would be better). (

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: I am not 100% sure. Try this sess.run([self.train, tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step(), self.train, self.loss], feed_dict)

Comment: Cheers, but it sadly still throws TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>

Comment: Concerning my update-the-neural-net-problem: I removed the update statements for now since I don't get it to work. I fixed the random seeds, so every one with the same parameters has the same results (doublechecked it). but if I then change my game implementation a small bit (changen the max number of ressource allowed), I get a small change in the result (= chosen actions in the last epoch differ 10%). Since the game is not consuming any Randoms, this leeds my to the conclusion that there already is an affect from the results to the neural network. But how?

Answer (score 0):

ok, basicly i didn't get that

```
self.train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.decent_pl[0]).minimize(self.loss)
```

is setting the *method* "train" and sess.run calls the method with parameters.
so i wrote a new learn method that works basicly.

```
def learn(self, sess, sta, vicp, dec):
    sta = np.expand_dims(sta, 0)
    vicp = np.expand_dims(vicp, 0)
    dec = np.expand_dims(dec, 0)
    sess.run(self.train, feed_dict={self.x_pl: sta, self.y_pl: vicp, self.decent_pl: dec})
```

the AI still acts stupid and often converges to 0 points, but that mus be my mistake probably at some other point.